# how to use more three channels input in train_datagen

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to apply Keras for images with more than three spectral channels. I noticed that `train_datagen` handles images with three channels based on color_mode='rgb'. Is there any way to increase the number input channels or are there any alternative methods?

```
img_train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                "train/image/",
                target_size=(64, 64),
                batch_size=batch_size,
                class_mode= None,
                color_mode='rgb',
                shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 1, 3 or 4 channels. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory).

> **color_mode** One of "grayscale", "rgb", "rgba". Default: "rgb". Whether the images will be converted to have 1, 3, or 4 channels.

An alternative is to use `tf.data.Dataset` for more control. There are [examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tfdata_for_finer_control) in the official documentation.

Comment: @ Nicolas Gervais, thanks for the info and links. does "tf.data.Dataset" allow for more than 4 channels?

Comment: You can load literally anything with it. I guess it mostly depends on the type of file you're loading. But if your filetype is supported, you can load any shape.